# IF and AND statement in R /R Studio

Tags: r, if-statement, merge

my data looks something like this:

```
Point   CODE  Area 
1.001   231   10
1.001   231   20
1.002   211   45
1.002   211   20
1.002   211   30
1.002   231   20
1.002   231   20
1.002   231   110
```

Where each `Point` is a unique value, each `CODE` is Unique, and `Area` is the area associated with each `CODE`.

I'm trying to `merge` the values in the case where the Point values are the same AND the `Code` values are the same, then the `Areas` under each `CODE` are added together, and the final resulting table looks like the following:

```
Point   CODE    TotArea
1.001   231     30
1.002   211     95
1.002   231     150
```

Any suggestions?

My file sizes are massive ( > 1 million rows), and I'm also new to `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(Point,CODE) %>%
         summarise(TotArea = sum(Area))
```